# How to resolve a 'NoneType Error' on my code?

Tags: python, class, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a binary tree deletion code on python.
In some reason, I got an error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right''.

When I tried to print the type of variable 'root', it says <class 'NoneType'>.

Also when I changed the
'root = None
insert(root, 50)'
to
'root = Node(50)',
it worked.

I'm guessing that there is some error on Class Definition or insert function. Can anybody help me?

```
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key, parent=None):               
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = parent


def insert(node, key):
    if node is None:
        node = Node(key)
        return node
    elif key < node.key:
        node.left = insert(node.left, key)
        node.left.parent = node
    else:
        node.right = insert(node.right, key)
        node.right.parent = node
    return node


def delete(node):
    if node.parent is None:
        node = delete_node(node)    # root
    elif node == node.parent.left:
        node.parent.left = delete_node(node)
    else:
        node.parent.right = delete_node(node)


def delete_node(r):
    if r.left is None and r.right is None:
        return None
    elif r.left is not None and r.right is None:
        return r.left
    elif r.left is None and r.right is not None:
        return r.right
    else:
        s = r.right
        while s.left is not None:
            sparent = s
            s = s.left
        r.key = s.key
        if s == r.right:
            r.right = s.right
        else:
            sparent.left = s.right
        return r


root = None
insert(root, 50)
insert(root, 99)
insert(root, 78)
insert(root, 57)
insert(root, 80)
insert(root, 4)
insert(root, 64)
insert(root, 35)
insert(root, 58)
insert(root, 33)

print(root.right.left.key)
start = timer()
delete(root.right.left)
print(timer() - start)
print(root.right.left.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` function creates the first node if it doesn't exist, but you ignore the return value. Instead, you should reassign it to `node`: `root = insert(root, 50)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the return type. If you reassign a variable in a function, it remains in the function scope. The variable is only mutated of it is already the object. That’s why your second example worked: you passed in a `Node` which was changed, while your first example didn’t: you created a `Node` and returned it.

You’ll want to reassign `root` in your first `insert` function.

```
root = assign(None, 50)
assign(root, 99)
…
```

As an aside, I often find it easier to split these functions into two. Your first one which returns a new `Node` might be called `create`, and you simply pass a value. After that you can call `assign` with the `root` node.

Comment: What you mean is that if I want to change a type of 'root' from 'NoneType' to 'Node Object', I have to reassign it to Node Object, to avoid the insert function to add a key to a None, Right?

And for my understanding, after I reassign a type to class object, I don't have to reassign it again cause its already a Node object. Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure I understand. The reason this works when you manually create a node object is that you’re then manipulating that object by reference. If you start with a `None`, you’re returning a new `Node` and you’re not actually doing anything with it. That’s why I recommended splitting the two functions. Right now your single `assign` function manipulates by reference and returns, but only manipulates a reference if it’s already a `Node` object, which can be a bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem has to do with the fact that when you assign a variable inside a function, that variable is edited locally, not globally. The easiest fix is to return the value from `insert`, `delete`, etc. instead of trying to assign it inside your functions:

```py
def some_func(x):
    if x is None:
        return 1
    else:
        return x + 1

x = None
x = some_func(x)
```